# How do you make a hexadecimal private key into a private key WIF Compressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoin

I am trying to make a python program to take the 64 character hexadecimal private bitcoin key and make it the 52 characters base58 WIF compressed private key.  If anyone has a python code snippet or even a formula I could reference it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm is:

```
//initialization
define version "80"
ByteString PK,CheckSum

//getting to work
    // double sha version+PK
CheckSum=SHA256(SHA256(version+PK).AsHex).AsHex
CheckSum=CheckSum.SubString(1,4) // first 4 bytes
    // now create base58
Result = base58encode(version+PK+CheckSum)
```

Not my friend that, this is a algorithm, pseudo code, not an actual code, unfortunately I dont know python, I use c/c++, just tried to be worthy and helpful.